# Get count of table in other table in other table

Tags: sql, database, count

Get count of table in other table in other table.

[image: Explanation Image]

I start with this code:

```
SELECT Nom_Folder,

(SELECT SUM(CountFiles) 
FROM (
SELECT  (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM files WHERE files.ConteurCategorie=categories.Conteur) AS CountFiles FROM `categories` WHERE categories.ConteurFolder=folder.Conteur
) X) AS NbrFiles


FROM folder
```

Comment: Please show us sample data which illustrates the problem.  This isn't a complete question as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Get Count of files inside the folders

Comment: What software, system, language are you asking about?

Comment: i use Mysql    ....

Answer (score -1):

i find the solution :) :)

```
SELECT folder.Nom_Folder, folder.Type, COUNT(files.Conteur) FROM folder INNER JOIN categories ON categories.ConteurFolder=Folder.Conteur INNER JOIN files ON files.ConteurCategorie=categories.Conteur GROUP BY Folder.Conteur
```